# How to execute a migration on project start

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations

I am looking to execute a migration command inside the start.cs file.
So when the application first runs, it looks for the database and if it does not exist then it runs the migration scripts.

I know you can do this in the package manager console with "dotnet migrations" but I am looking to do this through code.

Thanks!

---

## UPDATE

### Looks like this worked for me

- Inside my Startup.cs file, inside the Startup constructor method.

  ```
     using (
          var context = new PeopleContext(
              _config,
              new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<PeopleContext>()
          ))
      {
          context.Database.EnsureCreated();
      }
  ```
- I am using a "using" statement here to make sure my DbContext gets closed when I am done with it.
- After I create my **context** I then call its method to make sure the DataBase is there, if not then I add the dataBase and run migrations.

I am using ASP.NET Core : NETStandard, Version=v1.6

Pretty much the latest greates as of 9/1/2016

---

## Update 2

Looks like using the .Migrate() method may be the way to go.

### Note *

To use .Migrate() you will need to add

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Here is what I am using now.

```
        using (var context = new PeopleContext(_config,new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<PeopleContext>()))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Person.Any();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run EF7 Migrations on application startup for .Net Core, I have:

in ConfigureServices()

```
using (var dataContext = (DataContext)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(DataContext)))
            {
                dataContext.Database.Migrate();
            }
```

This runs the new migrations on startup.

I am not sure EnsureCreated will run new migrations after the initial table creation?
see: http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/ef7-ensurecreated-vs-migrate-methods/

Comment: Thanks... I will test this out.

Comment: This worked as well. I think when I accumulate more migrations, this will be the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I saw that if your database already exists and you run Migrate() again, you get problems. So I had to put a try catch for the DbContext. If the query throws an exception then I know the DB needs to be created and migrations ran.

Comment: It may be that you need to use 'Migrate' from the start, have you tried this from a new database?

Comment: When I used "context.Database.Migrate();" I get an error. I will mess around with it a little more here in a few days and see if I cant find a better solution. I will update this question when I find a better solution. But, right now this works for me. Thanks!

Comment: I have been using this for a while, adding migrations from powershell, This code will just run the migrations, and will error if the migration code errors. I suspect the issue is the migration code running against the database.